# ractivejs list sorting , ascending decending support?

Tags: ractivejs

Im trying to understand if there is a feature in ractivejs , for descending sorting , and ascending .
I couldnt find anyhting in the documentation .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - Ractive purposely avoids being a 'kitchen sink' utility library. But it's very easy to add an `ascending` or `descending` helper:

```js
var helpers = Ractive.defaults.data;

// assuming a and b are numbers...
helpers.ascending = function ( a, b ) {
  return a - b;
};

helpers.descending = function ( a, b ) {
  return b - a;
};

ractive = new Ractive({
  el: 'body',
  template: '' +
    '<p>ascending: {{ numbers.slice().sort(ascending) }}</p>' +
    '<p>descending: {{ numbers.slice().sort(descending) }}</p>'
  },
  data: {
    numbers: [ 9, 4, 6, 2, 4, 1, 10, 2, 7, 8 ]
  }
});
```

Note that you could also put the `ascending` and `descending` functions directly on the `data` object, if that's preferable.

Here's a JSFiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/rich_harris/nszt3150/

Comment: Just want to point out that if you do have a favorite sorting library, you can directly add that as your 'helper': `Ractive.defaults.data._ = _` and get the nice inline template access like in @Rich_Harris' fiddle example. VanillaJS or your favorite library, Ractive's good with that.